# Twig include render two time block

Tags: html, symfony, twig

I've some trouble with Twig. I don't understand why one of my block is rendering two time in my page.

**A-propos.html.twig**

```
{% extends "::layout-v2.html.twig" %}

{% set contexte = "a-propos" %}
{% block content %}
//some stuff
 {% block rightbar %}
            {{"Je suis dans le block de la vue rightbar"}}
            {{ parent() }}
 {% endblock %}
//some stuff
{% endblock %}
```

**layout-v2.html.twig**

```
{% include '::header/header-v2.html.twig' %}

<body class="">
{% block topBar %}
{% endblock %}

{% if app.user %}
    {% include '::layout-user-v2.html.twig' with {'view_content': block('content')} %}
{% else %}
    {% include '::layout-public-v2.html.twig' with {'view_content': block('content')} %}
{% endif %}


{% block rightbar %}
<div class="col-sm-3">
    {% if contexte is defined %}
            {% include 'BtpGeneralBundle:Sidebars:sidebar_contexte.html.twig' %}
        {% else %}
            {% include 'BtpGeneralBundle:Sidebars:sidebar_default.html.twig' %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% include '::footer/footer-js-v2.html.twig' %}

</body>
```

I don't understand why the view sidebar-context.html.twig is rendering first time on the right place and another time just before the include footer-js...

Thank

Comment: What does your footer twig file look like?

Comment: Please, provide sources for `footer-js-v2.html.twig`.

Comment: okay I understand why, it's because when I display block('content') it's display a first time the sidebar, and second time with the block rightbar in the layout. But how can I display one time without duplicate code in eath user layout and public layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split **{% block content %}** in *A-propos.html.twig* on two parts, e.g. **contetn1** before **rightbar** and **contetn2** after.